# Способом в Ubuntu 14.04 скомпилировать программу на C++ без установки программ дополнительных?

Tags: linux, gcc

При этом нужно не устанавливать build-essential. В системе уже есть g++
При компиляции через gcc выдаётgcc: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: Нет такого файла или каталога

Даёт ли вообще право, чистая Ubuntu скомпилировать исходник, без дополнительных инструментов?

Comment: Компилятор по определению является дополнительным инструментом. Было бы очень странно, если бы компилятор был в составе чистой Ubuntu.

Comment: Запускать обязательно нужно `g++`, а не `gcc`. Плюсовая прога так не соберётся.

Comment: Без установок, g++ команда не найдена

Comment: А как Вы собираетесь компилировать БЕЗ компилятора?